# dojo1.8 and form action: request post outside root directory

Tags: html, dojo

Hi I am using Dojo request.

I have no problem accessing a php file in the root directory 
from

```
request.post('process.php', ....});
```

But What if process.php file is in scripts folder outside 
root directory from,

```
request.post ('../scripts/'process.php',....}); It did not work.
```

And form tag in html

```
<form action='process.php' method='post'> it worked
```

But it did not work for

```
<form action='../scripts/process.php' method='post'>
```

So what are the correct ones?

Please advise 
Thanks in advance. 
Clement

Answer (score 0):

Access to folders outside the website root is normally forbidden.  There is very good and sound security reasons for this.  Hence, anything below the directory that your web address points to is out-of-bounds.

So, `http://www.mydomain.com/../scripts/process.php` is a definite no.  All code you wish to post to / interact with in the browser needs to be in an area accessible from your domain.  You may need to move the code in question so that it in a subdirectory of your domain root.

You can also, try something clever with symlinks or changes to .htaccess (if using Apache) or changing the server configuration.  However the best practice is to move the code to another directory.

Comment: in PHP it will work (depending on server settings) but when you are accessing via a url it won't.  This is a security measure, stopping people accessing root server files by using lots of ../ levels.  Otherwise a malicious user could access all your server's setting and gain access to unauthorised areas.  In a shared hosting environment this could include other peoples data too.